# jQuery .on already fired event

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do something like this after the DOM is loaded, the function still executes:

```
$(document).ready(fn)
```

However, the following does not execute the function if the 'myEvent' event has already been fired previously:

```
$(document).on('myEvent', fn)
```

Is there a **jQuery solution**, which does not require me to code my own event delegator, that fires previous events to a "late" event handler?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I believe you don't need that because that should point to a bad design decision.

Furthermore, it's fine getting `ready` event callback executed even if the document has already signaled that it's *ready*, **because this event happens once per page life-cycle**.

Just imagine that `click` event would allow you to do that you're requesting for but before adding the event handler the user clicked the target element more than once? **Would setting the event handler invoke it twice or more times?**